# UIScrollView Child ViewController Performance

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I'm adding `Child ViewControllers` to my `scrollView` via below to make the cards where a user can swipe between each card. This worked great in the beginning, but as the number of `Child ViewControllers` grew in my `scrollView`, the performance to instiate each suffered.

Is there a more efficient way to do this? Would a `UICollectionView` or `UITableView` work ?

```
            for(NSDictionary* tempDict in tempArray){
            MyViewController* VC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myVC"];;
            VC.myProperty = someProperty;
            VC.delegate = self;

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(self.scrollView.frame);
                CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(self.scrollView.frame);
                CGFloat x = self.scrollView.subviews.count * width;
                VC.view.frame = CGRectMake(x, 0, width, height);

                [self.scrollView addSubview:VC.view];
                [self addChildViewController:VC];
                [VC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(x + width, height);
            });
        }
```

Comment: It depends on, on which event this code block is being executed?

Comment: @Mrunal After In viewDidLoad, I call a method to query my database and return results. Than this is called in the main thread